# Make non editable a checkbox after other is selected java

Tags: java, checkbox

let's say we have 10 checkboxes, How would you make after you choose One, other checkbox is non editable or selectable for example

[image]

If we choose checkbox A, the checkbox -A must be non editable or selectable.

Is this possible?

Comment: Is this web? Use radio, by default only one can be selected.

Comment: nope java GUI, is it better to use radio?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, apply a SelectionListener to your Control and Disable all other Controls with a loop through all your controls.

```
b1.addSelectionListener(new SelectionAdapter() {
  public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent e) {
     for(Control child : composite.getChildren()){
        if(child != b1) {
           child.setEnable(false);
        }
     }
  }
});
```